# Where should I submit bug reports for the pattern lock?

Tags: security, lock-screens, bugs

I believe i found a bug with the pattern lock.

Where should I submit bug reports for the pattern lock?

*Note*: this might just be a Sense thing:

1. Create a pattern lock.
2. Lock phone.
3. Wake phone draw pattern. Hold finger on screen and not activate any more points (so that it has your valid pattern)
4. Let screen go dark.
5. Release finger.
6. Rewake phone.
7. Phone should unlock.

Comment: Is that the expected behavior?  I would not expect it to unlock in that situation.  While unlocking in that case is *probably* not a security issue, remaining locked is definitely not a security issue.

Comment: I would expect the pattern lock to release its state when the phone resleeps so it forces me to draw my pattern.

Comment: I was able to reproduce what you listed, so it is not just sense. but I was only able to get it to do it once out of the 5 or so times I tried. Once of the times, the screen turned off, and before i could even remove my finger, it came back on and was unlocked.

Comment: It probably depends on the digitizer.

Comment: If you reported the issue, can you edit your question and put the link to that as well. That way people can find the result of the issue, like if it is "the desired operation", or fixed, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The android issue tracker is located at http://b.android.com. you can report the issue there.

Comment: That link redirects to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 3):

[The Android issue tracker can be found here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)